# Calculator Coding - adding fraction buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a sample calculator `JavaScript` kit, and I'm trying to modify it to add some fraction buttons (convert decimal to fraction & vice versa, using numbers to make a fraction, for example pressing 2 then a button then pressing 4 and makes it 2/4 or 1/2, and then doing the same for a number after the division symbol so it's like 2/4 divided by 1/2. Here's the calculator code, with the head script and body itself.

## HEAD

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" id="calculator">
function addChar(input, character) {
    if(input.value == null || input.value == "0")
        input.value = character
    else
        input.value += character
}

function cos(form) {
    form.display.value = Math.cos(form.display.value);
}

function sin(form) {
    form.display.value = Math.sin(form.display.value);
}

function tan(form) {
    form.display.value = Math.tan(form.display.value);
}

function sqrt(form) {
    form.display.value = Math.sqrt(form.display.value);
}

function ln(form) {
    form.display.value = Math.log(form.display.value);
}

function exp(form) {
    form.display.value = Math.exp(form.display.value);
}

function deleteChar(input) {
    input.value = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - 1)
}

function changeSign(input) {
    if(input.value.substring(0, 1) == "-")
        input.value = input.value.substring(1, input.value.length)
    else
        input.value = "-" + input.value
}

function compute(form) {
    form.display.value = eval(form.display.value)
}

function square(form) {
    form.display.value = eval(form.display.value) * eval(form.display.value)
}

function checkNum(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var ch = str.substring(i, i+1)
        if (ch < "0" || ch > "9") {
            if (ch != "/" && ch != "*" && ch != "+" && ch != "-" && ch != "."
                && ch != "(" && ch!= ")") {
                alert("invalid entry!")
                return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
}
</SCRIPT>
```

## BODY

```
<center><div id="calculator">
    <FORM NAME="sci-calc">
    <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="1">
    <TR>
    <TD COLSPAN="5" ALIGN="center"><INPUT NAME="display" VALUE="0" SIZE="28" MAXLENGTH="25"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE=" exp " ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { exp(this.form) }"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  7  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '7')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  8  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '8')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  9  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '9')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="   /   " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '/')"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  ln   " ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { ln(this.form) }"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  4  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '4')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  5  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '5')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  6  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '6')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="   *   " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '*')"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE=" sqrt " ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { sqrt(this.form) }"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  1  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '1')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  2  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '2')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  3  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '3')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="   -   " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '-')"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  sq  " ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { square(this.form) }"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  0  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '0')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="   .  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '.')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE=" +/- " ONCLICK="changeSign(this.form.display)"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="   +  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '+')"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="   (    " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '(')"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="cos" ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { cos(this.form) }"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE=" sin" ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { sin(this.form) }"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE=" tan" ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { tan(this.form) }"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="   )   " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, ')')"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="clear" ONCLICK="this.form.display.value = 0 "></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center" COLSPAN="3"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="backspace" ONCLICK="deleteChar(this.form.display)"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="enter" NAME="enter" ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { compute(this.form) }"></TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </FORM>
    </div>
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: I don't know what resource you used to code this, but `center` is a long-deprecated element, as are some of the attributes you've used within your table (`ALIGN`, `CELLSPACING` and `CELLPADDING`). All styling should be done through CSS.

Comment: Cerbrus; The question is what JavaScript math functions can I use to convert decimals to fractions? James Donnelly; I didn't code this, I got it from a site called JavaScript Kits or something like that. I used it as a sample starting point for the idea I have in mind; making a complete scientific calculator with fractions and decimal conversion compatibility.

Comment: There is no JS Math function to do that. You're going to have to write something yourself.

Comment: Also, nobody uses CAPS for html any more. Just stick to lower case: `<form name="sci-calc">` etc.

Comment: Once again, I didn't do it. But I'll figure something out, @Cerbrus.